# deleting a file from the data base by clint

Tags: php

```
function appoint_del(sat,sat1)
{
  if(confirm("Are You Sure To delete Selected Person Details Completely?"))
  {     
     document.form1.action="student.php?cedit="+sat+"&did="+sat1;//
     document.form1.submit();//an alternative to call form
  }
}

<?
   if($_GET['did']!="")
   {
     $del=executeupdate("delete from table2 where id=".$_GET[did]);     
     redirect("student.php?succ=3");
   }
?>
```

To delete the content in data base by clint I have successfully did the job but I am not completelly aware of what is happining by the statement1 `document.form1.action="student.php?cedit="+st+"&did="+st1;`
and statement2
`document.form1.submit()`

can any one explane it?
and can sugest any good reference book for clarifing these type of doubts?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.form1.action="student.php?cedit="+sat+"&did="+sat1;
```

This line of JavaScript sets a html form's action to the student.php page and appends the two parameters "cedit" and "did" along with their values.  I assume you have a form on your page somewhere.

```
document.form1.submit();
```

This submits that form.  I don't know where to or by what method (POST, GET) because you haven't provided any details on the form.  I assume it submits back to the same page because the next line is a handler:

```
if($_GET['did']!="")
```

This detects whether the form was submitted by checking if the "did" parameter is present.

```
$del=executeupdate("delete from table2 where id=".$_GET[did]);
```

This seems to execute a database query with a massive SQL injection vulnerability.  Very dangerous.

```
redirect("student.php?succ=3");
```

Redirects back to the same page again, this time passing in a different "succ" parameter which I assume is handled via some other code that you haven't provided.